# Flutter: video_player fails if played 14 or more times

Tags: flutter, dart, exoplayer, video-player, audioflinger

I got a list of videos using **photo_manager** package and whenever I play videos for more that 14, **video_player** package fails. I already tried seeking the current video to 0 second when I initialize another video again but it still doesn't fix. Here's the error:

```
E/AudioTrack(18666): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
E/AudioTrack-JNI(18666): Error -12 initializing AudioTrack
E/android.media.AudioTrack(18666): Error code -20 when initializing AudioTrack.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(18666): Playback error.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(18666): com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioSink$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(48000, 12, 48000)
```

Comment: This looks like an error in the package. You'd probably get better mileage from posting this on the issues page of the package's GitHub.

Comment: Oh... damn. Yeah sure pal, thanks much!